# Returning C struct array

Tags: objective-c, c, opengl

Hello stackoverflow fellow members?

#### Struct Declaration in class A

```
struct PointSprite 
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat size;
    Color4f color;
} ParticleSystems[MAXIMUM_PARTICLES_ON_SCREEN];
// I generally put some stuffs in ParticleSystem array. 
// for ex) struct PointSprite *ps = &ParticleSystems[index];
// and it works well on the class A, but I want to get class B to access this array.
```

My question is, how am I suppose be return the array of '**ParticlelSystems**' array so that other class can access to it? I have tried below code to return the pointer, but compiler gives me a warning.

```
- (struct ParticleSystems *) commitParticles
{
    struct ParticleSystems *ptr = &ParticleSystems; // it said, assigning incompatible pointer type
    
    return ptr;
}
```

Or should I need to allocate the '**ParticleSystems**' array? Please help ! Thanks

Comment: The correct answer is different in C, C++, and objective-c. Please pick one language for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the array inside the function then you should dynamically allocate it using `new` and then return a pointer to it.

You cannot return arrays from a function, you will have to return a pointer to it.

Sample Code:

```
ParticleSystems* doSomethingInteresting()
{
    ParticleSystems *ptr = new ParticleSystems[MAXIMUM_PARTICLES_ON_SCREEN];

    //do the processing

    return ptr;

}
```

The caller takes the ownership of the returned dynamically allocated array and needs to deallocate it to avoid memory leaks:

```
delete []ptr;
```

Comment: While you're technically correct, in C++ I'd use a std::vector instead of a regular array. If you want to avoid the overhead of copying the vector data around, instead of using a plain pointer I recommend using a boost::shared_ptr, i.e. `shared_ptr<vector<PointSprite>> ptr(new vector<PointSprite>>`.

Comment: @datenwolf: Absolutely, One really needs to use RAII and almost never use raw pointers in C++, but again if the OP already knows the number of elements of his array, then it would make sense to use a array rather than a `std::vector` to avoid the overhead of extensive allocations a vector would make.

Comment: You can initialize a std::vector with a size, then stay within the bounds of that size. That way no reallocation will occcur: `typedef std::vector<PointSprite> PointSprite_vector; boost::shared_ptr<PointSprite_vector> ptr(new PointSprite_vector(size))`.

Comment: Or you can use vector::reserve to pre-allocate the memory; then you can do all the push-backs you want up to that pre-allocated limit. I do this a lot to prevent extra allocations, while not having to run the default constructor alot.

Answer (score 2):

You can either return it, after allocating one, or you can fill one passed to you by the user. The latter leaves the responsibility to the user to provide a ParticleSystem to the method which receives the data. It can be a local array, or a malloced one.

```
- (void) commitParticles: (ParticleSystems *) sprites
{
    // set members of the structs here
}
```

I prefer this kind of passing to returning a malloced array. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `assigning incompatible pointer type` compiler warning because your `ptr` declaration should be of type `PointSprite *`, not `ParticleSystems *`